# How the util of iostat is computed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

```
iostat -x -d
```

can display many i/o statistic info. 
For util of iostat, the explanation is :

> Percentage of CPU time during which I/O requests were issued to the device (band-width utilization for the device). Device saturation occurs when  this  value  is close to 100%

I want to know how the util was computed?

I make an experiment, (see following code), start 40 thread to randomly read 40 files. I suppose the disk util should be very high, but I am wrong, 
the iostat is as follow, anyone can give why? THX

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sdb1              0.01     0.44  0.24  0.57     3.44     8.14    14.34     0.00    2.28   0.66   0.05
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

void* work(void* a)
{
    int* id = (int*)a;
    string file = "sys.partition";
    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf, "%d", *id);
    file.append(string(buf));
    ifstream in(file.c_str());
    in.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
    size_t len = in.tellg();

    cout << "open file : " << file << " , " << len << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(true)
    {
        size_t pos = rand() % len;
        in.seekg(pos);
        //cout << pos << endl;
        in.read(buf, 10);
        system("sync");
    }
    in.close();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    static const int num = 40;
    pthread_t threads[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)       {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, work, &i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)       {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the format is totally changed, the overflow should improve editor.

Comment: the overflow to the rescue! Improvement Done!

Comment: either look at the changes that @zengr has kindly made to your question or read the formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`%util` is named busy in the source code of iostat: https://code.google.com/p/tester-higkoo/source/browse/trunk/Tools/iostat/iostat.c#380

Busy is counted as percent ratio of `Ticks` to `deltams`, limited to 100%

```
busy = 100.0 * blkio.ticks / deltams; /* percentage! */
if (busy > 100.0) busy = 100.0;
```

DeltaMS is sum of system load for the period of time (user time + system time + idle time + iowait)/ ncpu.

```
double deltams = 1000.0 *
        ((new_cpu.user + new_cpu.system +
          new_cpu.idle + new_cpu.iowait) -
         (old_cpu.user + old_cpu.system +
          old_cpu.idle + old_cpu.iowait)) / ncpu / HZ;
```

Ticks - is the `Time of requests in queue` for the period

```
blkio.ticks = new_blkio[p].ticks
                - old_blkio[p].ticks;
```

In more current version of sysstat the code is bit different: 
http://sources.debian.net/src/sysstat/10.2.0-1/iostat.c#L959

```
/*       rrq/s wrq/s   r/s   w/s  rsec  wsec  rqsz  qusz await r_await w_await svctm %util */
printf(" %8.2f %8.2f %7.2f %7.2f %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f %7.2f %7.2f %7.2f %6.2f %6.2f\n",
...
       /*
        * Again: Ticks in milliseconds.
        * In the case of a device group (option -g), shi->used is the number of
        * devices in the group. Else shi->used equals 1.
        */
       shi->used ? xds.util / 10.0 / (double) shi->used
                 : xds.util / 10.0);    /* shi->used should never be null here */
```

xds is filled in the `compute_ext_disk_stats(&sdc, &sdp, itv, &xds);` http://sources.debian.net/src/sysstat/10.2.0-1/common.c?hl=679#L679

```
/*
 * Macros used to display statistics values.
 *
 * HZ is 1024 on IA64 and % should be normalized to 100.
 */
#define S_VALUE(m,n,p)  (((double) ((n) - (m))) / (p) * HZ)

xds->util  = S_VALUE(sdp->tot_ticks, sdc->tot_ticks, itv);
```

And there is the filling of tot_ticks from iostat.c

```
  * @ioi        Current sample statistics.
  * @ioj        Previous sample statistics.
  * @itv        Interval of time.
  ...

sdc.tot_ticks = ioi->tot_ticks;
sdp.tot_ticks = ioj->tot_ticks;
```

`tot_ticks` are read from  "*sysfs stat for current block device or partition*" in `read_sysfs_file_stat` ([iostat.c:487](http://sources.debian.net/src/sysstat/10.2.0-1/iostat.c#L474)), and `ioi` and `ioj` are current and previous stat.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't know how to accept your answer?

Comment: @Raymond, did you get, what does "Time of requests in queue" mean? I can't understand this parameter fully, but i think it is something like mean time between issuing and fulfilling of disk requests

Comment: But ... what's the answer to the OP question `I suppose the disk util should be very high, but I am wrong, the iostat is low, anyone can explain why?`

Comment: This is called caching: OS cached file data read from disk in the page cache: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache - real disk utilization reported by iostat was low, lower than 1%, so the *author's test was incorrect*, it did not measure any disk latency/speed, only how OS manages to service random requests from memory.

Answer (score 13):

`iostat -x` (I used [an old version of the source code](http://web.archive.org/web/20130228140001/http://tester-higkoo.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/Tools/iostat/iostat.c) to write this up before realizing it) displays information from `/proc/diskstats` (documented [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt)) and `/proc/stat` (for CPU times; see [man proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)) (and a few others, but that's not important for understanding).

You can see the relevant snippets of code in osgx's answer, but I couldn't make sense of them in isolation, so here's an extended explanation:

- `%util = blkio.ticks / deltams * 100%`
- `deltams` is the time elapsed since last snapshot in ms. It uses CPU stats from `/proc/stat` presumably because it gives better results than to rely on system time, but I don't know for sure. (Side note: for some reason the times are divided by `HZ`, while the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) states it's in `USER_HZ`, I don't understand that.)
- `blkio.ticks` is "# of milliseconds spent doing I/Os", from [`/proc/diskstats` docs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt):

  ```
  Field  9 -- # of I/Os currently in progress
    The only field that should go to zero. Incremented as requests are
    given to appropriate struct request_queue and decremented as they finish.
  Field 10 -- # of milliseconds spent doing I/Os
    This field increases so long as field 9 is nonzero.
  ```

  i.e. my understanding is that `ticks` is the number of ticks when any I/O request (for this device) was in progress multiplied by the duration between ticks.

So `%util = 100%` means that each time the kernel looked (I guess it's 1000 times per second on modern kernels, see "HZ"), an I/O request was in progress.

Here's an excerpt from [another post on iostat](http://dom.as/2009/03/11/iostat/):

> [%util is] how much time did the storage device have outstanding work (was busy).
>
> In proper RAID environments it is more like “how much time did at least one disk in RAID array have something to do”. I’m deliberately excluding any kind of cache here – if request can be served from cache, the chance is quite negligible it will show up in %util, unlike in other values.
>
> What this also means – the RAID subsystem can be loaded from 6.25% (one disk doing the work) to 100% (all of them busy). Thats quite a lot of insight in single value of ’100%’, isn’t it?

Comment: If the average queue size (avgqu-sz) is seen to be more than 1 on all the iostat samples (lets say 1 sec samples over 100 seconds), does that mean utilization will be 100% for those 100 seconds? Because having a big queue size means that device had sufficient I/Os to process.

Comment: I don't think that's right, if you're considering 1-second [averages](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues/126#issue-178552770) - people claim that `await = avgqu-sz * svctm / (%util/100)`. On the other hand if the queue is _always_ non-empty (and not simply averages 1/second), I'd expect %util to be 100.

Answer (score 3):

As per the man page, the first line of results from iostat is an average from the moment the system was booted.

From my tests, this seems to apply also to the only line, if called e.g. as

```
iostat -x.
```

Try:

```
iostat -dmx 1 5
```

It will give you five lines with one second difference between lines. Discard the first, look at the others, perhaps like that the output will make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

%util means how much time spent writing/reading per unit of time, you can compute it from the mean service time:

```
svctm  * (  r/s + w/s )  /1000 
= 0.66 *(0.24 + 0.57) /1000
= 0.0005346
```

hence 0.05%

I haven't read your code, but obviously at less than 1 read or write per second it isn't loading the disks that much!