# how to get disk read/write bytes per second from /proc in programming on linux?

Tags: linux, profiling, disk

**purpose** :i want to get information like `iostat` command can get .

I have already known that if open `/proc/diskstats` or `/sys/block/sdX/stat` there are information that :*sectors read* and *sectors write*. So if i want to get read/write bytes/s ,the following formula is right ?

> **read/write bytes per second**:
>   (sectors read/write(now)-sectors read/write(last))*512 bytes/time interval
>
> **read /write  operations per second** :
>   (read/write IOs(now)+read/write  merges(now)-read/write IOs(last)-read/write  merges(last ))/time interval

So if i have a timer that every second control software read the information from those two files ,and then using the above formula to calculate the value .Can i get the correct answer ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Disk Read/Write in Linux with C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525390/calculating-disk-read-write-in-linux-with-c)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

TLDR Sector is **512 bytes** ([octets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)); 1 sector is 512 bytes; each bytes is 8 bits; every bit is either 0 or 1, but not superposition of them).

"The standard sector size of 512 bytes for magnetic disks was established ....*[dubious – discuss]* " (c) wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector

How to check sector size for io statistics (in `/proc`) in linux:

Check how `iostat` tool works (it shows kilobyte per second when started as `iostat 1`) - it is part of sysstat package:

https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/iostat.c

```
 * Read stats from /proc/diskstats.
void read_diskstats_stat(int curr)
...
        /* major minor name rio rmerge rsect ruse wio wmerge wsect wuse running use aveq */
        i = sscanf(line, "%u %u %s %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %u %u %u %u",
               &major, &minor, dev_name,
               &rd_ios, &rd_merges_or_rd_sec, &rd_sec_or_wr_ios, &rd_ticks_or_wr_sec,
               &wr_ios, &wr_merges, &wr_sec, &wr_ticks, &ios_pgr, &tot_ticks, &rq_ticks);

        if (i == 14) {
....
            sdev.rd_sectors = rd_sec_or_wr_ios;
....
            sdev.wr_sectors = wr_sec;
....

 * @fctr    Conversion factor.
...
        if (DISPLAY_KILOBYTES(flags)) {
            printf("    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn\n");
            *fctr = 2;
        }
...
    /*       rrq/s wrq/s   r/s   w/s  rsec  wsec  rqsz  qusz await r_await w_await svctm %util */
    ... 4 columns skipped
    cprintf_f(4, 8, 2,
          S_VALUE(ioj->rd_sectors, ioi->rd_sectors, itv) / fctr,
          S_VALUE(ioj->wr_sectors, ioi->wr_sectors, itv) / fctr,
```

So, read sector count and divide by two to get kilobyte/s (seems like 1 sector read is 0.5 kb read; 2 sector read is 1 kb read and so on). We can conclude that the **sector is always 512 bytes**. Same is stated in the doc, isn't it?:

internet search for "/proc/diskstats" ->

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/procfs-diskstats ->

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt "I/O statistics fields" by ricklind from usa's ibm

```
Field  3 -- # of sectors read
    This is the total number of sectors read successfully.

Field  7 -- # of sectors written
    This is the total number of sectors written successfully.
```

*No info about sector size here* (why?). Is the source code being the best documentation (it may be)? The writer of `/proc/diskstats` is in kernel sources in file `block/genhd.c`, function `diskstats_show`:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/genhd.c?v=4.4#L1149

```
1170                 seq_printf(seqf, "%4d %7d %s %lu %lu %lu "
1171                            "%u %lu %lu %lu %u %u %u %u\n",
...
1176                            part_stat_read(hd, sectors[READ]),
...
1180                            part_stat_read(hd, sectors[WRITE]),
```

Structure `sectors` is defined in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/genhd.h?v=4.4#L82

```
 82 struct disk_stats {
 83         unsigned long sectors[2];       /* READs and WRITEs */
```

It is read with  `part_stat_read` and written with `__part_stat_add`

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/genhd.h?v=4.4#L307

Adding to the `sectors` counter ... is... at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/blk-core.c?v=4.4#L2264

```
2264 void blk_account_io_completion(struct request *req, unsigned int bytes)
2265 {
2266         if (blk_do_io_stat(req)) {
2267                 const int rw = rq_data_dir(req);
2268                 struct hd_struct *part;
2269                 int cpu;
2270 
2271                 cpu = part_stat_lock();
2272                 part = req->part;
2273                 part_stat_add(cpu, part, sectors[rw], bytes >> 9);
2274                 part_stat_unlock();
2275         }
2276 }
```

It uses hard-coded "`bytes >> 9`" to compute sector size from request size in bytes (why round down??) or for human, not no-floating-point compiler, it is the same as `bytes / 512`.

There is also `blk_rq_sectors` function (unused here...) to get sector count from request, which does the same `>>9` from bytes to sectors
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/blkdev.h?v=4.4#L853

```
841 static inline unsigned int blk_rq_bytes(const struct request *rq)
842 {
843         return rq->__data_len;
844 }

853 static inline unsigned int blk_rq_sectors(const struct request *rq)
854 {
855         return blk_rq_bytes(rq) >> 9;
856 }
```

Authors of FS/VFS subsystem in Linux says in reply to https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/8/17/234 "Why is SECTOR_SIZE = 512 inside kernel ?" (2015):

```
 #define SECTOR_SHIFT 9
```

Message https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/8/17/269 by Theodore Ts'o:

> *It's cast in stone.*  There are too many places all over the kernel,
>   especially in a huge number of file systems, which assume that the
>   sector size is 512 bytes.  So above the block layer, *the sector size
>   is always going to be 512.*
>
> This is actually *better* for user space programs using
>   /proc/diskstats, since they don't need to know whether a particular
>   underlying hardware is using 512, 4k, (or if the HDD manufacturers
>   fantasies become true 32k or 64k) sector sizes.
>
> For similar reason, st_blocks in struct size is always in units of 512
>   bytes.  We don't want to force userspace to have to figure out whether
>   the underlying file system is using 1k, 2k, or 4k.  For that reason
>   the units of st_blocks is always going to be 512 bytes, and this is
>   hard-coded in the POSIX standard.

Comment: Hmm, why iostat divides value by 2, not multiplies (`s_value()/fctr`)?

Comment: @osgx, there is counter of read_sectors: for example, in 1 second 54 sectors were read, each of 512 bytes. So, to get kilobytes per second, we should convert read_sectors to read_kilobytes; sector is 512 byte, kilobyte is 1024 byte, so kilobyte is 2 sectors long. When we divide s_value (read_sectors) by 2 we will get 27 kilobytes per second, so fctr is used correclty.

Comment: This answer have been so truly answered in a such complete and deep way that I can only just quit my searches. THANKS!

Comment: @MaxCuttins, the only problem is with %util field of iostat.. Better answer needed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458183/how-the-util-of-iostat-is-computed - %util is like percentage of block io ticks when there were at least one request in progress ("at flight").

Comment: I wrote a bash script using this concept: https://github.com/seffparker/nagios-plugins/blob/master/check_iokbps